# Can't always read session cookie

Tags: php

I have a page (mypage.html) which sets a cookie as follows:

```
setcookie ("sessionid", md5 (uniqid (rand())));
```

Now, at the top of an include which displays the site header I have the following:

```
echo "cookie is ". $_COOKIE['sessionid'];
```

When I am on mypage.html, which includes the header, the echo command displays the cookie name, as it should...e.g.

> cookie is 4d40102ff2d2268d907dd31debc411e2 cookie is 4d40102ff2d2268d907dd31debc411e2

But if I move aeway from the page which set the cookie, all I see is

> cookie is

with no name - If I go back to mypage.html it reads it again with no problem. I have no clue how this can happen?? Any ideas?

Comment: Better use $_SESSION instead of $_COOKIE.

Comment: You're welcome Darren. And @powtac is right, if you'll use this var in the context, SESSION is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an explicit path for the cookie. The default is the current directory only, so if you navigate to a script in another directory, the cookie won't be sent back by the browser.

```
// Cookie is valid for all paths ( / ) in the current domain
// This also has an explicit expiry time of 1 hour from the time it's set...
setcookie ("sessionid", md5 (uniqid (rand())), time() + 3600, "/");
```

It's a little unusual to be setting your own session cookies though, when simply initiating a session handles it for you:

```
session_start();
// Id is set for you...
echo session_id();
```